# Fteching javadoc and jar files for my local maven repository

Tags: maven, maven-2, javadoc

My local maven repository has grown over a period of time.
On hind sight, I should have fetched the javadocs and sources for the repository; however I didn't.

Is it possible to force maven to fetch the javadocs and source for all the artefacts available in my local repository (of course only for the artefacts that have a javadoc or source attached)?

I am not trying to download individual javadoc and source jar file and attach them using mvn deploy command, but rather update for all available artefacs in my local repo; may be using a single command if possible :-)

Comment: Take a look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't think this resolves my query. I am looking to update the src and javadoc for the entire local maven repository. Or else I might have not understood your answer correctly. Can you please specify any particular section I need to look into in the maven URL you mentioned?

Comment: The above goal will download the javadoc/sources files for the project you are in. For all in does not exist such call/command etc.